# Поворот текста textpath

Tags: svg, xpath, d3.js

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно подписать при помощь d3.js `path` элемент?

Я знаю, что подписывается с элементом `textpat .attr("#href"....)`.
Когда линия идет слева на право - все нормально, текст читается, но когда линия закругляется, то текст переворачивается, а если линия идет справа  налево - текст вообще в верх ногами. Как это можно исправить?

Допустим рассчитать угол `path` сегмента в определенной точке и применить трансформацию. Я не нашел информации по этому поводу.
Может ли мне кто-нибудь подсказать, как это исправить?
Как пересчитать положение подписи в пространстве?
Так же у меня подписи повторяются по всей длине линии.

`getTotalLength` - получаю полную длину, затем

```
for(var i = 100/*начало исчисления линии в пикселях*;i<path.getTotalLength , i=i+400)
```

Затем получаю координаты

```
getPointAtLength(i)
```

и подписываю элемент, но это я устанавливаю туда текст, но не отрисовка вдоль линии.

Comment: так и не нашел ответа, поэтому прибегнул к старому дедовскому способу через выявление точки подписи и поворота текста вдоль линии по нужному мне углу через тангенс угла по двум точкам линии и созданной третьей